# Failed to Fetch Updates when I try to update in app center

Tags: updates, error

My OS version is 5.1.7 Hera. I got the following error when I try to update in app center:

```
 - W: GPG error: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG DFA175A75104960E Emulators OBS Project <Emulators@build.opensuse.org>
 - E: The repository 'https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease' is not signed.
 - W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
 - W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
 - E: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG DFA175A75104960E Emulators OBS Project <Emulators@build.opensuse.org>)
 - W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
 - W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list:3
```

I tried `sudo-apt-update`, `sudo-apt-upgrade`, `sudo-apt-autoremove`, but still error.
I also tried `apt-get clean`, `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`, `apt-get clean`, `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, but still got error.

I don't understand how to fix it. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will resolve your issue:

```
wget -qO - https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works!

Answer (score 0):

*[Solved]  Thanks to D.Foerster
https://github.com/davidfoerster/aptsources-cleanup/releases/tag/v0.1.7.5.1
Can easily follow this:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/760896/how-can-i-fix-apt-error-w-target-packages-is-configured-multiple-times
It works fine for me, but still not understanding why it happens*

It seems to be almost the same problem. It start when i tried to install autopsy from repo.
Tried to fix but still having problems. Anyone can help?

```
W: L'obiettivo Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-it_IT) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-it) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-large (restricted/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-it_IT) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-it) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (restricted/binary-amd64/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (restricted/binary-i386/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-it_IT) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-it) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (restricted/i18n/Translation-en) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11 (restricted/dep11/Components-all.yml) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-small (restricted/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (restricted/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-large (restricted/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-amd64) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo CNF (restricted/cnf/Commands-all) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-it_IT) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-it) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo DEP-11-icons-large (main/dep11/icons-128x128.tar) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
W: L'obiettivo CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) è configurato molteplici volte in /etc/apt/sources.list:42 e /etc/apt/sources.list:46
```